# Why do you have to pass sizeof in socket functions?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm looking into socket programming in C and I'm curious why do you have to pass a parameter **and** a length of that parameter in functions like `bind()` and `connect()`?
Why not just use `sizeof()` inside of the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it gives a simple simple way to handle many different types of protocols with the same API.

Since a socket can use many different underlying protocols (as pointed out by @larsman), the call can't know which type of structure it's being handed, exactly. There's some basic "inheritance" going on with the various `struct sockaddr` types.

Also, it provides some forward compatibility; it's possible that a binary compiled against one version of the library is run against a later version, in which the address type might have grown (for instance to support IPv6).

By passing the *caller's* idea of the size to the called function, the called function can take care not to overwrite memory.

Comment: And forward compatibility, and because the socket functions are designed to deal with all kinds of connections, not just Internet Protocol, but IPX, NETWARE, local pipes and so on.

Comment: It's not backward compatibility. It's because the sockets API caters to differently-sized address structures by design; in the very first version, it already supported IPv4 and UNIX domain sockets (`sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_un`) using one set of functions. XNS was added pretty soon.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks, that's true of course. Perhaps it's even the main reason ... I'll edit once more!

Comment: Correction after reviewing sources: even XNS was already in the first sockets implementation, 4.2BSD -- one of the reasons for implementing it was to show that the sockets API worked for other protocol stacks than TCP/IP with a single API.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you the third argument to

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

You can't do `sizeof(addr)` inside the function, since that would just return the size of the pointer, not the struct pointed to. `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` also won't work since different address families (local sockets, IPv4, IPv6, exotic network protocols) have differently-sized `sockaddr`-like types.

E.g., for an IPv4 socket, you call

```
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
// set up my_addr
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

but for a local (Unix) domain socket, you pass a `sockaddr_un` which has a potentially different length.

[On my Linux box, `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) == 16` but `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un) == 110`.]

If you're used to object-oriented programming, then you can think of the `sockaddr` family as a (shallow) class hierarchy with dynamic typing. `struct sockaddr` is the abstract base class, `bind`, `connect`, etc. are the methods. Since C doesn't have built-in dynamic typing, it has to be emulated and passing the size of the structure is part of that.